# SQL Query SELECT RECORDS

Tags: sql, select

How can I get the first 100 records of the column name starting from the name John?

Thanks.

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: The correct answer to this question is rdbms specific. MySql uses `limit`, SQL Server uses `top`, other databases probably have other ways to do it as well....

Comment: Just to confirm... We're assuming that you're explicitly *sorting* on the `name` column.  Is that correct?

Comment: "*the first 100 records of the column name*" - that makes no sense at all. There is no such thing as the "record of a column"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Anahi Reyes. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Some additional detail will assist others in providing answers, such as an example data set, the query you have attempted and your desired result.

Comment: Sorry, the name of the column is "NAME". I tried to use limit but it seems that only works with integers and no with strings.

Comment: Show what you have tried and tag what RDBMS you are using. That will help us get you a quicker answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for get the first 100 records for a table we use the limit clause. See the following  Example.

Question: Get the first 100 persons that his name is starting for John

Answer: Select * from pearson where name like 'John%' limit 100